# How do terrain-based unit promotions work?

Tags: civilization-5

If I promote a unit so that it is better a fighting of rough terrain for example.

When I am in combat and attacking an enemy, who needs to be in the rough terrain them or me for me to receive the bonus?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In general, it is determined by the tile on which the *attacked* unit is standing.

So, in case of melee units, it's where the combat takes place - i.e. in the hex containing the defending unit.

In case of ranged units, attack bonuses depend on the hex on which the target is standing.

Comment: I checked in game, the bonus specifically says that it applies based on where the target is.

Comment: So in summary? In all cases it is where the defending unit is standing that counts?

Comment: Thank you, I've been wondering this. I wish Firaxis had worded the upgrades more clearly, you can take their wording either way.

Comment: Does the upvoted comment by @bwarner mean that the accepted answer is incorrect?