# In Civ5, for the two promotions for combat bonus in open vs. rough terrain, which terrain applies for ranged combat?

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do unit attack bonuses work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8281/how-do-unit-attack-bonuses-work)

When an archer has one of these promotions, which terrain applies? - The terrain the archer is located upon, or the terrain the enemy unit is located?

Note: Manual says:

- Accurancy : ... ranged combat strength against units in open terrain (anything but
  Hills, Forest, or Jungle).
- Barrage : ... ranged combat strength against units in rough terrain (Hills, Forest, or
  Jungle).

Comment: Hey Oak - if it's closed as exact duplicate it would really be nice if the duplicate question could be linked in via comment. Cheers! (or did I miss something?)

Comment: Duplicate link is at the top of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all that matters is the terrain your enemy is on. As you mentioned, the manual says: "against **units in** open/rough terrain".